# how to get string rather than object when filtering a data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, object, subset

I am filterig a dataframe who`s columns are:  'pandas.core.series.Series'
and each element of the column is a string 'str'
But when I filter the dataframe I get:  'pandas.core.series.Series'
and not the element I want to obtain.

```
people_pipe.Empresa[people_pipe['Correo electrónico']=='dae@mrboho.com']
```

OUT:

1    Mrboho
Name: Empresa, dtype: object

rather than getting:

```
people_pipe.Empresa[1]
```

OUT:

'Mrboho'

Comment: Can You paste code of dataframe?

Comment: this dataframe I obtain it from a csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the Series object to an array of strings

```
people_pipe.Empresa[people_pipe['Correo electrónico']=='dae@mrboho.com'].values
```

You can also try to typecast the series objects to string

```
people_pipe.Empresa[people_pipe['Correo electrónico']=='dae@mrboho.com'].astype(str)
```